# Angular 4 get queryString

Tags: angular, location, query-string

Making an angular onboarding page for a corporate website. People will navigate to the page via a link in a welcome email which will contain a user specific token. I need to get this token out of the url querystring and use it in all ajax calls for auth purposes. My problem is reading the querystring.

Angular version is 4.2.4

I have combed through pages of docs on the '@angular/common' Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy and have copy pasted the import and adding them to the providers, I get error after error after error. I can't find a simple example anywhere of importing location and using it to get the querystring from the page url. If this were javascript it's a super simple couple lines of code. Why is this so difficult? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What I tried:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

providers: [Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}],
```

**page.services.ts**

```
constructor(private location: Location) {
  console.log('location: ', location);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using Angular's [`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) in the `@angular/router` package. Import it into your module as you do with the others, and inject it into your component as you already are with `Location`. Then you can access the `queryParamMap` like:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  console.log(route.snapshot.queryParamMap);
}
```

That will return a [`ParamMap`](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) interface, which was actually inspired by `URLSearchParams` interface :)

You can do things like `route.queryParamMap.get('myQueryParam')` and it works as you would expect.

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question or if you need more information.

Comment: That was great! Thanks. Hadn't even noticed that option.

Comment: For Angular 6, I get null back for my parameter, as there are no parameters.

Comment: This answer may be obsolete. At least since v10, queryParamMap has been an Observable.

Comment: In regard to the update from @JohnChurchill here, the instant value is available from [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot).