# How to use ActivatedRoute in Angular 5?

Tags: angular5, query-string, angular-activatedroute

I am trying to do exactly the same thing as in this post: [Angular 4 get queryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508226/angular-4-get-querystring)

I am using Angular 5.2.5.

ActivatedRoute seems to be the thing to use to retrieve querystring values off the URL when the user first visits the website.  However, I am unable to figure out what I need to import to be able to use ActivatedRoute.

Could someone specify exactly what needs to be added to the app.module.ts file, and the component.ts file where I am trying to use ActivatedRoute?

This post specifies adding routing to the imports array of the @NgModule: [No provider for ActivatedRoute - Angular 2 RC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942817/no-provider-for-activatedroute-angular-2-rc5).  However, I don't have an app.routing.ts file.  Do I have to create an app.routing.ts file to use ActivatedRoute?

Answer (score 19):

**ActivatedRoute** Contains the information about a route associated with a component loaded in an outlet. 
It can also be used to pass data from `one component` to `another component` using route such as Id, flag, state etc.

```
http://localhost:4200/quiz/edit_quiz/032
```

`032` being `id` of the quiz you wanna edit.

Get this id in your component(in my case let it be **edit_quiz.compontent.ts**) to use by using Activated Route.

**Step 1:** Import ActivatedRoute from Router module.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

**Step 2:** Inject ActivatedRoute in constructor.

```
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

**Step 3:** Get id on a local variable named `quizId` in `ngOnInit(){}`

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.quiz_id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
   }
```

Now we have id in `edit_quiz.component.ts` to use.

Answer (score 3):

I made the two changes Arun suggested.  Then, to fix the "No provider for ActivatedRoute" error, I made the changes shown below.

1) I added this line to the app.module.ts:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

2) I added this line to the imports array of the @NgModule in app.module.ts:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([])
```

This article gave me the fix: [Angular error: no provider for ActivatedRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039457/angular-error-no-provider-for-activatedroute)

Now it compiles.  Hooray!

Answer (score 2):

You need to import ActivatedRoute from @angular/router like

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

then add this line to the imports array of the @NgModule in app.module.ts:

```
imports:[
        ........,
        RouterModule.forRoot()
],
```

then you can use any where as below:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
     console.log(route.snapshot.queryParamMap); // this
}
// or
queryString : string;
getQueryString(){
   this.queryString = this.route.queryParamMap.get('myQueryParam');
}
```

No. You don't need app.routing.ts if you don't have to navigate pages within your app.

Comment: So I added the import line and the constructor parameter to my component.ts file, but now I get this error:

ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SubmitPaymentComponent -> ActivatedRoute]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SubmitPaymentComponent -> ActivatedRoute]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

Comment: ohh sorry i forgot to say about the provider.. you figured it out by yourself.. that's great !!!

Answer (score 2):

**How to Get Route Parameters:**
The Angular Router provides two different methods to get route parameters:

a. Using the route snapshot(ActivatedRoute),

b. Using Router Observables

**ActivatedRoute in Angular:** 
Provides access to information about a route associated with a component that is loaded in an outlet

**Step-1** Import the ActivatedRoute interface

`import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';`

**Step-2** Inject the ActivatedRoute in Constructor

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}`

**Step-3** To fetch a employee object by the given id and assign that object to its local employee property.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.employee = new Employee();
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

Note: **Property   Description**

```
  snapshot: The current snapshot of this route
```

Answer (score 0):

**ActivatedRoute**

I'm late to the conversation but hope the following works for the future programmers who encounter the same issue.

import the ActivatedRoute

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

Inject the dependency injection

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }
```

and to grab the id from the link you can use the following

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.product = products[+params.get('productId')];
  });
}
```